# Django exclude query, can i pass multiple parameters?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-2.2

I have a query and i want to exclude null companies as well as specific user email.

```
Demo.objects.all().exclude(company__isnull=True, email="abc@gmail.com")
```

but seems like above exclude does not work with multiple arguments, my return queryset has email="abc@gmail.com" in it.

If i try above query with single arguments, it works. but not working with multiple arguments.
Anyone has any idea how to pass multiple arguments in django exclude ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can do this, but then you say *exclude all `Demo`s that have `company__isnull=True`, and as `email` `'abc@gmail.com'`*. This thus means that if only *one* of the two conditions is met, it is *not* excluded.

You can work with `Q` objects, like:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Demo.objects.exclude(
    Q(company__isnull=True) |
    Q(email='abc@gmail.com')
)
```

But it is likely more readable with:

```
Demo.objects.exclude(
    company__isnull=True
).exclude(
    email='abc@gmail.com'
)
```

this will thus exclude items for which `company` is `NULL` *and* exclude items for which `email` is `'abc@gmail.com'`. So here we exclude it from the moment *at least* one condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Queries are lazy, nothing happens until you try to pull data from it, so there's no downside to using .exclude() more than once.

```
Demo.objects.exclude(
    company__isnull=True
).exclude(
    email='abc@gmail.com'
)
```

Another way is to use Q objects that can be combined using the & and | operators.

```
# Import
from django.db.models import Q

# Exclude query
exclude_query = Q()
exclude_query.add((~Q(company__isnull=True), Q.OR)
exclude_query.add((~Q(email="abc@gmail.com"), Q.OR)

# Get final objects which excludes email "abc@gmail.com" and null companys
result = Demo.objects.filter(exclude_query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is not right, this is excluding every Demo that has no company and has an email of `abc@gmail.com`. You may want to chain `exclude()` calls instead.

```
Demo.objects.all().exclude(company__isnull=True).exclude(email="abc@gmail.com")
```